# How to set a WiX RegistryValue relative to the install path

Tags: wix, registry, relative-path

This leaves me with \Default.udl

```
<RegistryKey Key="Software\My Company\Product\Connections" Root="HKCU">
  <RegistryValue Name="Default" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]\Default.udl" Type="string" />
</RegistryKey>
```

I'd like something like C:\Program Files\Company\Product\Default.udl

Comment: do you use INSTALLLOCATION as directory Id (and not, for example, INSTALLDIR or APPLICATIONFOLDER)?

Comment: At the time I wrote the question I wasn't using any, now i'm using Application Folder. The strange thing was that I could successfully create a key with the correct path using just Install location, but not with a filename appended afterwards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of a few things that could be causing the issue.

Are you sure your directory layout is correct? It should look something like this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="My Company">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Product">
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I believe the `HKCU` hive is meant to be used only in a per-user install, but the path you specified is under Program Files. You might want to take a look at the [Installation Context documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd765197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the differences between per-user and per-machine installs. In some versions of Windows, `ProgramFilesFolder` has a different value in per-user mode.

Alternatively, if your installer is laying down the Default.udl file, you could use the [#filekey] [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx) to point directly to that file.

```
<RegistryValue Name="Default" Value="[#Default.udl]" Type="string" />
```

Comment: Great, I actually went with APPLICATIONFOLDER, but I'll switch to [#FILE] notation when I get the chance. Your answer was clear and included relevant bonus info about installation context that might've really opened my eyes last week!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of INSTALLLOCATION use [TARGETDIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That sets it to C:\\Default.udl